# r match data in two data frames then check text in another column for matched row

Tags: r, if-statement, match, grepl

I have two data frames stu1 and stu2. Both have matching ID columns but different variables in other columns.

For example, `stu1`:

```
ID, Grade, Group, Age
ad1, A, Green, 14
bc1, B, Green, 13
cd1, B, Blue, 14
fs3, C, Red, 13
```

`stu2`:

```
ID, Prog, Loc, Year
bc1, LSC1, Ext, 2013
cd1, LSC1, Ext, 2013
cd1, BSC1, Int, 2013
ad1, BSC2, Int, 2012
rs2, KHL4, Ext, 2014
```

What I'm trying to do is check whether the student ID in `stu1` exists in `stu2` then check whether the text in another column for the corresponding row matches my string, e.g. `Prog =='BSC*'` then create a new column in `stu1` which states "Yes" or "No".

So, the result for `stu1` should be:

```
ID, Grade, Group, Age, BSCProg
ad1, A, Green, 14, Yes
bc1, B, Green, 13, No
cd1, B, Blue, 14, Yes
fs3, C, Red, 13, No
```

I've tried a number of different ways unsuccessfully, e.g:

```
stu1$BSCProg <- ifelse(stu2[grepl("BSC", stu2$Prog) & match(paste0(stu1$ID), 
    paste0(stu1$ID)),], "Yes", "No")

stu1$BSCProg <- ifelse(is.na(match(paste0(stu1$ID),
    paste0(stu2$ID) & stu2[grepl("BSC", stu2$Prog),])),"No","Yes")

stu1$BSCProg <- ifelse(stu1$ID %in% stu2$ID & grepl('BSC', stu2$Prog), "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by merging the two tables so that you can do column comparisons. Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(stu1)
setDT(stu2)

dat <- merge(stu1,
             stu2[Prog %like% "BSC", .(ID, BSCProg = Prog)],
             by = "ID",
             all.x = TRUE)

dat[, BSCProg := ifelse(is.na(BSCProg), "No", "Yes")]
```

Result:

```
#     ID Grade Group Age BSCProg
# 1: ad1     A Green  14     Yes
# 2: bc1     B Green  13      No
# 3: cd1     B  Blue  14     Yes
# 4: fs3     C   Red  13      No
```

Unpack that a bit, the first step is to merge the `ID` and `Prog` columns from `stu2` into `stu1`. The `Prog %like% "BSC"` section will merge only those rows where the `Prog` column has "BSC" as part of the value. `BSCProg = Prog` is to rename the column to what you want in the end.

When this is done, the values of the column will be `NA` or values like `BSC1`, `BSC2`. The final statement `BSCProg := ifelse(is.na(BSCProg), "No", "Yes")` will change any `NA` to "No" and turn anything else to "Yes".

Comment: Thank you! That was awesomely quick and sooo helpful! you're wonderful :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I've now been asked to create new columns for every program. There are only 5 programs so I've been able to copy and paste the code to change the search and add new columns each time. Rather than that and to improve my R skills, is there a simpler and cleaner way to add additional columns to search for the other programs (LSC, BSC 1 & 2, KHL1:4)? I've tried playing around with the existing suggestions but they all failed too.

Comment: Try using `dcast` which is in the `data.table` package. It will let you create a column for each entry in Prog.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Haven't had the chance to try it yet but at least I know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` by `ID` first, then create your new columns. Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(stu1, key="ID")
 setDT(stu2, key="ID")
 stu1 = merge(stu1, stu2, all.x=TRUE)
 stu1[, BSCProg:=ifelse(grepl("^BSC", Prog), "Yes", "No")]
```

Comment: Similar to mine, and the way I did it originally too. The problem is in `stu2` there is a repeat of `cd1` in the ID column, so after the merge `stu1` gains a row, and has two values of `BSCProg`.

Comment: Good catch! I should have tried on the example data!

Comment: Thanks for trying this too! This might be helpful if I have to add extra rows to the original data (haven't been asked yet but wouldn't be surprised if that comes up too!). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution. `stu3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

stu1 <- data_frame(ID = c("ad1", "bc1", "cd1", "fs3"),
                   Grade = c("A", "B", "B", "C"),
                   Group = c("Green", "Green", "Blue", "Red"),
                   Age = c(14, 13, 14, 13))

stu2 <- data_frame(ID = c("bc1", "cd1", "cd1", "ad1", "rs2"),
                   Prog = c("LSC1", "LSC1", "BSC1", "BSC2", "KHL4"),
                   Loc = c("Ext", "Ext", "Int", "Int", "Ext"),
                   Year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2014))


stu3 <- stu1 %>%
  full_join(stu2 %>% select(ID, Prog), by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(BSCProg = ifelse(grepl("BSC", Prog), "Yes", "No")) %>%
  drop_na(Grade) %>%
  select(-Prog) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(BSCProg)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `left_join` be better here than `full_join`?

Comment: @ChiPak Because `stu2` have duplicated `ID`, such as `cd1`. `left_join` will lose those duplicated rows.

Comment: `left_join(stu1, select(stu2,ID,Prog), by="ID")` keeps `cd1`. Anyways, just a suggestion.

Comment: @ChiPak `left_join` is my first thought, but it was not working.

Comment: When I tried `full_join`, it looked messy. I thought `left_join` might clean up your output a little, but if it doesn't save code in the end, then there's no point replacing it. Cheers

Comment: @ChiPak `full_join` looks messy because if you just copy paste the `read.csv` part. It creates whitespace in the `ID` column. I will fix that `read.csv` command.

Comment: Thanks for trying too! I also tried those joins but they were very messy and we have lots of students in the lists. Eric Watt's response works a treat!

Comment: @Leila, @ChiPak. Join is not messy. What causes the problem was the way I created the example dataset. The `read.csv` command works on my laptop, but when I copied pasted to SO, extra whitespace changes the `ID` column, thus making the `full_join` command not working.  If you have time, please try my solution a gain because I have fixed the input data using `data_frame` command.

Comment: @Leila Erid Watts' answer is great and you should accept that. But I want to be clear that join function from `dplyr` is completely capable of such operation. Next time, if you want to post your example datasets. Please use `dput`. That would make data sharing more precise and accurate in the format.

Comment: Apologies! I didn't mean to cause offence if I did. I've tried @ycw 's method and it worked a treat too! Thanks for the fast responses and effort!